# I tried to created dictionary in dictionary but I struggled

Tags: python

I tried to created a get_dict function that takes a parameter as a filename and then creates and returns a dictionary which contains

key is the number of the product code and has
value is a dictionary that contains
key is a string of sizes (S, M, L, or XL), and
value is the number of the product.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIJGE.png)

I tried this.

```
def get_dict(file_name):  

    d={}
    e={}
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            alist = line.split()
            e[alist[1]] = alist[2]
            d[alist[0]] = e
    print (d)
```

the output is look like this

```
{'4125': {'M': '4', 'L': '7', 'XL': '3'}, '5645': {'M': '4', 'L': '7', 'XL': '3'}, '7845': {'M': '4', 'L': '7', 'XL': '3'}}
```

but I expect that output will be like this
{4125: {'S': 1, 'M': 4}, 5645: {'L': 7}, 9874: {'S': 8}, 9875: {'M': 8}, 7845: {'S': 10, 'XL': 3}}

Text file example
7845 XL 3
4125 S 1
5645 L 7
9874 S 3
4125 M 4

Comment: can u send what is written in the filename so i can figure what is happening

Comment: `e` is always the same dictionary, so all the keys in `d` have the same value. You need to create one dictionary for each key in `d`.

Comment: Now, I have attached the file picture in the post, which would help. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_dict(file_name):  

d={}
with open(file_name) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        alist = line.split()
        if not alist[0] in d:
            d[alist[0]] = {alist[1]: alist[2]}
        else:
            d[alist[0]].update({alist[1]: alist[2]})
print(d)
```

You have to update the dictionary instead of overwriting the same key value. The above solution should work.

Output -

```
{'7845': {'XL': '3'}, '4125': {'S': '1', 'M': '4'}, '5645': {'L': '7'}, '9874': {'S': '3'}}
```